# I recently attempted to install Unity Desktop Environment! It didnt work out!

Tags: unity, 20.04

I have recently tried to install Unity desktop environment by running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Once the Desktop Environment is installed I restarted. I log in to find out that Unity doesn't work and it just crashes upon login.

- Ubuntu VER 20.04
- GNOME VER 3.36.2
- PC SPECS:

  - Intel core i3
  - Intel integrated graphics
  - 4 GB of ram
  - 1 TB hard drive

Comment: Retry with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop` . Then select Unity session on the login screen.

Comment: pomsky: I simply did sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop and then rebooted!